# Actionscript 3, trace doesn't trigger, cant get past error 1026

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I can't find anything online that is helpful here, but I am making a project for school, where the timeline animations are only within movieclips, and two buttons trigger a sunrise and a sunset. I got error 1026, which pointed me to the movieclip, and specifically to the actions panel "stop();" code. Got rid of that, now 1026 just points at the symbol itself.

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;


    public class Buttons extends MovieClip {


        public function Buttons() {
            // constructor code

            sunrise.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onClickRise)
        }

        private function onClickRise(evt:MouseEvent):void {
            trace ("Clicked Rise");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: First, you should provide the error description, not just its number. If you don't, there's one more step of googling for any helper to do, which is bad, since you totally could do that. Then, my guess is that you have some object (**MovieClip**, **Sprite**, **SimpleButton** or maybe **TextField**) as a child to that **MovieClip** with the instance name of **Buttons**. Am I correct?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit that in, basically, it's a circle converted to a button symbol with both class and instance name sunrise, Buttons is the name of my actionscript class.

Comment: No. The error means that there's something inside named **Buttons**, that collides with the constructor name and results in error 1026. Try changing the class name to something like **But123tons** in order to avoid that collision.